# What happen to my validation using cakephp3.4.13?

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

It always says 'This value is already in use' eventhough not yet present in database.

Sometimes it will say "This field cannot be left empty"

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {

$validator
    ->integer('id')
    ->allowEmpty('id', 'create'); 

   $validator->requirePresence('username', 'Please enter username.');
$validator
    ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('password', 'You must enter a password', 'create')
        ->add('password', [
            'length' => [
            'rule' => ['minLength', 8],
            'message' => 'Passwords must be at least 8 characters long.',
        ]
    ]);
$validator
    ->requirePresence('age', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('age');
$validator
    ->requirePresence('address', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('address');
$validator
    ->email('email')
    ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('email');
$validator
    ->requirePresence('gender', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('gender');
return $validator;
    }


public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;
    }


    <?php
    namespace App\Model\Entity;
    use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
    use Cake\ORM\Entity;

    /**
     * User Entity.
     */
    class User extends Entity
    {

        protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
        ];
        protected function _setPassword($password)
        {
           return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
        }
    }
?>
```

I cant register or add more data now, unlike before I can add or register, I recently updated the version of my cakephp, I also added, gender, address and age fields in database

Im a newbie,

Comment: what is in your buildRules?

Comment: I added the code above bro @rrd

Comment: The error messages means you try to save a record with the same username what you already have in the database

Comment: nope, even that username and email is not yet existed in the database, it will always. says that error    @rrd

Comment: for which filed do you get the error message? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-entities

Comment: here is the error, https://imgur.com/OkyCTpM     @rrd

Comment: It is strange. It looks like your application removes the username. Maybe it is accessible false on the entity class?

Comment: I already added my entity class? is that you mean?   please help me how to resolve this one @rrd

Comment: hm. This looks ok. Than the problem is somewhere else but based on these  information. Is your code somewhere online?

Comment: its local only? what other files you want to see bro @rrd, im stuck with these

Comment: I am out of ideas. So what I would do is install your app on my local server and debug where the problem occurs.

Comment: do i need to display the error in the register method in userscontroller.php?

Comment: what you mean your local server?

Comment: hi @rrd please help me on this. im practicing cakephp i cant proceed now because of this

Comment: I can not help you without testing your code. For that it should be available somewhere online for download.

Comment: @rrd  this is my new code in validation still not working   https://gist.github.com/xiandan2018/   im using cakephp3.4.13

Comment: I have downloaded your code into a cake 3.4.13 install and I was able to register myself at least without an image.

Comment: where i gone wrong bro? i could not find any revisions in the code? what files did you change @rrd

Comment: upload your full userscontoroller to gist. That is tha only file what I touched. But I think you have some problem elswere. Anyway let me see your controller first.

Comment: bro @rrd   did you add a code in register method????

Comment: No, I just made a full controller class from the code you provided, as it was just a register method, not a full controller. Check it here: https://gist.github.com/rrd108/01b25bad0a949b298ef64aa5fcb27718

Comment: no, error still the same "'This field cannot be left empty'"

Comment: that is why I think that error mesaages is fired by something what you have did not show me. I would reccomend you to learn debuggin and find where the error happens.

Comment: what yout hink bro @rrd the register method in controller got an error? or the userstable? please help me

Comment: replace your controller with mine in the gist and let's what happens

Comment: i already replace my controller with your code still the same bro

Comment: than without getting all your code I can not help you further

Comment: this is my whole userscontoller.php including your code  https://gist.github.com/xiandan2018/9983cf3197558cc7ed2c1166f55e2826#file-userscontroller-php

Comment: @rrd  please help me...  bro

Comment: I have checked your code, and again it successfully save a new user via the register method. I do not want to guess where is the problem as it can be a lot of things. But if I can not reproduce the error, I can not help you solve it.

Comment: @rrd Im confused why in your side its ok? while on my side not ok?

Comment: that means the error occurs somewhere else in your code. That is why I told you without seeing all of your code (everything) I can not reproduce the error. If I can reproduce I can not help. Why don't you upload the hoe thing to a github repo? Or bitbucket where you can have free privte repos

Comment: what you mean @rrd the whole files? i will upload in github ?

Comment: all files what belongs to the project. Practically everything in your project folder.

Comment: let me ask something? bro does my code affect the version of cakephp, this  project is function normally then i upgraded to cakephp3.5.2, since  their is a problem in installation, I re updated t version cakephp3.4.13  @rrd

Comment: no it should not make an error like that on version changing

Comment: i removed the validation for username it will not give error but after saving in database no username data stored in database "empty"  @rrd

Comment: @rrd do you have suggestion on it? when i click register button it will submit but.. the username field in the database is empty

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself and the culprit for me was the 'isUnique' call on the field. My issue was the email field and it didn't need to be unique.

Additionally, after changing a model on a production environment you must clear the cache for newly submitted fields to go into the db.
'cake cache clear_all'.

I wasn't able to post a comment.

Comment: I already comment the isunique in buildRules, and clear all cache but error still occur

Comment: `dd($user);` after patchEntity and after Users->save().
This will show you if there is some kind of form error or if data isn't being patched into the entity.

Comment: after Users->save()   ''it will not display on debug just the error in the form "This field cannot be left empty"